# PHP download is 0 bytes from USB, permissions?

Tags: php, download

im having an issue downloading a file using php. It was working until i recently installed my webserver on a usb stick to test out some new modifications before going live.

Everything worked until i was testing it out on the USB stick to note, however after running the server from the usb stick i was able to download a file, however it was 0 bytes.

I am using a fairly standard download technique that has been documented across the internet :

```
//test if a parameter was passed
if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
if (!empty($_GET['download'])) {
$files = $_GET['download'];
download($files);
}
}

//download function
function download($files){

if(!file_exists($files)){
die('Error');
}else{
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
ob_start();
flush();
readfile($files);
exit;
}
}
```

I believed the check to see if the file exists line would prevent the ability to download a file that doesent exist...yet im able to download an empty file.

At the moment im believing that it may be a privileges issue but iv been unable to verify that looking online as the file does exist on both usb and harddrive so maybe it passes the test but isnt allowed to read from usb?

Comment: Is `filesize($file)` a copypaste error or actual error?

Comment: Hmm it was like that in the original..but I will try changing it to see if it works.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen actually this worked and fixed my problem, was an oversight that somehow worked anyway post it as an answer and I'll accept it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable for checking the file size so you always tell the recipient that the size is zero.

You should have `filesize($files)` instead.